# PITest skips tests in ant

Tags: ant, mutation-testing, pitest

I have the problem, that PITest skips some of my tests. It reports no line coverage for the tested class and all mutations in stay alive:

> replaced return value with Collections.emptyList for ... → NO_COVERAGE

The list below is empty:

> Tests examined

I did check the following:

- the class file of class and test is supported in one of the directories in the classpath
- the test is not excluded
- tests in the same directory are run
- source directory is provided correctly
- no errors occur on the console, even when logging with verbose=true
- I logged and checked all parameters

```
<pitest
                pitClasspath="pit.path"
                classPath="mutation.path"
                targetClasses="my.package1.*,my.package2.*,my.package3.*"
                targetTests="my.package1.Class1Test,my.package2.sub.Class2Test,my.package3.sub.Class3Test"
                reportDir="pitest"
                sourceDir="src,testsrc"
                timestampedReports="false"
                outputFormats="HTML,XML"
                excludedClasses="my.package1.*Test,my.package2.*Test,my.package3.*Test"
                verbose="true"
        />
```

I am using PITest version 1.4.11, but I tested as well with 1.6.2 and 1.4.3. Also I'm using Java 1.8.0_211 and ant 1.9.13.

I set up a test project at:
https://github.com/johannesn/pittestskippingtests

This is the log output for this sample project:

```
Buildfile: .../pitestskipingtests/build.xml

mutationCoverage:
   [delete] Deleting directory .../pitestskipingtests/classes
   [delete] Deleting directory .../pitestskipingtests/testclasses
    [mkdir] Created dir: .../pitestskipingtests/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: .../pitestskipingtests/testclasses
    [javac] .../pitestskipingtests/build.xml:30: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to .../pitestskipingtests/classes
    [javac] .../pitestskipingtests/build.xml:31: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to .../pitestskipingtests/testclasses
   [pitest] 19:24:08 PIT >> INFO : ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [pitest] 19:24:08 PIT >> INFO : Enabled (+) and disabled (-) features.
   [pitest] 19:24:08 PIT >> INFO : -----------------------------------------
   [pitest] 19:24:08 PIT >> INFO : +FFBLOCK        Filters mutations in code duplicated by finally block inlining
   [pitest] 19:24:08 PIT >> INFO : +FSTATI         Filters mutations in static initializers and code called only from them
   [pitest] 19:24:08 PIT >> INFO : +FSEQUIVEQUALS  Filters equivalent mutations that affect only performance in short cutting equals methods
   [pitest] 19:24:08 PIT >> INFO : +FFEACH         Filters mutations in compiler generated code that implements for each loops
   [pitest] 19:24:08 PIT >> INFO : +FINFINC        Filters mutations to increments that may cause infinite loops
   [pitest] 19:24:08 PIT >> INFO : +FFLOOP         Filters any mutations to increments in for loops as they may cause timeouts
   [pitest] 19:24:08 PIT >> INFO : +FRETEQUIV      Filters return vals mutants with bytecode equivalent to the unmutated class
   [pitest] 19:24:08 PIT >> INFO : +FINULL         Filters mutations in compiler generated code that checks for null by calling getClass
   [pitest] 19:24:08 PIT >> INFO : +FTRYWR         Filters mutations in code generated for try with resources statements
   [pitest] 19:24:08 PIT >> INFO : +FKOTLIN        Filters out junk mutations in bytecode created by compiler for kotlin language features
   [pitest] 19:24:08 PIT >> INFO : +FSTATINIT      Filters mutations in static initializers and code called only from them
   [pitest] 19:24:08 PIT >> INFO : +FLOGCALL       Filters mutations in code that makes calls to logging frameworks
   [pitest] 19:24:08 PIT >> INFO : +FINFIT         Filters mutations that may cause infinite loops by removing calls to iterator.next
   [pitest] 19:24:08 PIT >> INFO : +FANN           Filters mutations in classes and methods with matching annotations of class or runtime retention
   [pitest] 19:24:08 PIT >> INFO :   [annotation]    Annotation to avoid (full package name not required)
   [pitest] 19:24:08 PIT >> INFO : -CLASSLIMIT     Limits the maximum number of mutations per class
   [pitest] 19:24:08 PIT >> INFO :   [limit]         Integer value for maximum mutations to create per class
   [pitest] 19:24:08 PIT >> INFO : -EXPORT         Exports mutants bytecode and other details to disk
   [pitest] 19:24:08 PIT >> INFO : ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [pitest] 19:24:08 PIT >> FINE : Running report with ReportOptions [targetClasses=[my.package1.*, my.package2.*, my.package3.*], excludedMethods=[], excludedClasses=[my.package1.*Test, my.package2.*Test, my.package3.*Test], excludedTestClasses=[], codePaths=[], reportDir=pitest, historyInputLocation=null, historyOutputLocation=null, sourceDirs=[src, testsrc], classPathElements=[.../pitestskipingtests/resources/pitest/pitest-1.4.3.jar, .../pitestskipingtests/testclasses, .../pitestskipingtests/classes, .../pitestskipingtests/lib/junit-4.12.jar], mutators=[], features=[], dependencyAnalysisMaxDistance=-1, jvmArgs=[], numberOfThreads=1, timeoutFactor=1.25, timeoutConstant=4000, targetTests=[^my\.package1\.Class1Test$, ^my\.package2\.sub\.Class2Test$, ^my\.package3\.sub\.Class3Test$], loggingClasses=[], maxMutationsPerClass=0, verbose=true, failWhenNoMutations=true, outputs=[HTML, XML], groupConfig=TestGroupConfig [excludedGroups=[], includedGroups=[]], fullMutationMatrix=false, mutationUnitSize=0, shouldCreateTimestampedReports=false, detectInlinedCode=false, exportLineCoverage=false, mutationThreshold=0, coverageThreshold=0, mutationEngine=gregor, javaExecutable=null, includeLaunchClasspath=false, properties={}, maxSurvivors=-1, excludedRunners=[], includedTestMethods=[], testPlugin=junit, useClasspathJar=false]
   [pitest] 19:24:08 PIT >> FINE : System class path is .../pitestskipingtests/resources/pitest/pitest-1.4.3.jar:.../pitestskipingtests/resources/pitest/pitest-ant-1.4.3.jar:.../pitestskipingtests/resources/pitest/pitest-entry-1.4.3.jar:.../pitestskipingtests/resources/pitest/xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar:.../pitestskipingtests/resources/pitest/xstream-1.4.11.1.jar:.../pitestskipingtests/lib/junit-4.12.jar
   [pitest] 19:24:08 PIT >> FINE : Maximum available memory is 3641 mb
   [pitest] 19:24:08 PIT >> FINE : MINION : Installing PIT agent
   [pitest] 
   [pitest] 19:24:09 PIT >> INFO : Sending 3 test classes to minion
   [pitest] 19:24:09 PIT >> INFO : Sent tests to minion
   [pitest] 19:24:09 PIT >> FINE : Coverage generator Minion exited ok
   [pitest] 19:24:09 PIT >> INFO : Calculated coverage in 0 seconds.
   [pitest] 19:24:09 PIT >> FINE : Used memory after coverage calculation 14 mb
   [pitest] 19:24:09 PIT >> FINE : Free Memory after coverage calculation 231 mb
   [pitest] 19:24:09 PIT >> FINE : According to coverage no tests hit the mutation MutationDetails [id=MutationIdentifier [location=Location [clazz=my.package1.Class1, method=method1, methodDesc=()Ljava/lang/String;], indexes=[4], mutator=org.pitest.mutationtest.engine.gregor.mutators.ReturnValsMutator], filename=Class1.java, block=1, lineNumber=5, description=mutated return of Object value for my/package1/Class1::method1 to ( if (x != null) null else throw new RuntimeException ), testsInOrder=[], isInFinallyBlock=false, poison=NORMAL]
   [pitest] 19:24:09 PIT >> FINE : According to coverage no tests hit the mutation MutationDetails [id=MutationIdentifier [location=Location [clazz=my.package2.sub.Class2, method=method1, methodDesc=()Ljava/lang/String;], indexes=[4], mutator=org.pitest.mutationtest.engine.gregor.mutators.ReturnValsMutator], filename=Class2.java, block=1, lineNumber=5, description=mutated return of Object value for my/package2/sub/Class2::method1 to ( if (x != null) null else throw new RuntimeException ), testsInOrder=[], isInFinallyBlock=false, poison=NORMAL]
   [pitest] 19:24:09 PIT >> FINE : According to coverage no tests hit the mutation MutationDetails [id=MutationIdentifier [location=Location [clazz=my.package3.sub.Class3, method=method1, methodDesc=()Ljava/lang/String;], indexes=[4], mutator=org.pitest.mutationtest.engine.gregor.mutators.ReturnValsMutator], filename=Class3.java, block=1, lineNumber=6, description=mutated return of Object value for my/package3/sub/Class3::method1 to ( if (x != null) null else throw new RuntimeException ), testsInOrder=[], isInFinallyBlock=false, poison=NORMAL]
   [pitest] 19:24:09 PIT >> INFO : Created  3 mutation test units
   [pitest] 19:24:09 PIT >> FINE : Used memory before analysis start 23 mb
   [pitest] 19:24:09 PIT >> FINE : Free Memory before analysis start 222 mb
   [pitest] 19:24:09 PIT >> FINE : Running 3 units
   [pitest] ================================================================================
   [pitest] - Mutators
   [pitest] ================================================================================
   [pitest] > org.pitest.mutationtest.engine.gregor.mutators.ReturnValsMutator
   [pitest] >> Generated 3 Killed 0 (0%)
   [pitest] > KILLED 0 SURVIVED 0 TIMED_OUT 0 NON_VIABLE 0 
   [pitest] > MEMORY_ERROR 0 NOT_STARTED 0 STARTED 0 RUN_ERROR 0 
   [pitest] > NO_COVERAGE 3 
   [pitest] --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [pitest] ================================================================================
   [pitest] - Timings
   [pitest] ================================================================================
   [pitest] > scan classpath : < 1 second
   [pitest] > coverage and dependency analysis : < 1 second
   [pitest] > build mutation tests : < 1 second
   [pitest] > run mutation analysis : < 1 second
   [pitest] --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [pitest] > Total  : < 1 second
   [pitest] --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [pitest] ================================================================================
   [pitest] - Statistics
   [pitest] ================================================================================
   [pitest] >> Generated 3 mutations Killed 0 (0%)
   [pitest] >> Ran 0 tests (0 tests per mutation)
   [pitest] 19:24:09 PIT >> INFO : Completed in 0 seconds

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

Comment: I don't think this can be answered without a minimal project that replicates the problem.

Comment: I guess you are right... I'll try to set one up.

Comment: I don't know why, but in my sample project, I don't get any test running... See https://github.com/johannesn/pittestskippingtests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a hell of a lot of debugging and trying things out, I found out that test methods were not found because the junit dependency hamcrest-core was missing.

For everyone else experiencing a problem like this, try debugging the following method:

```
org.pitest.junit.RunnerSuiteFinder#apply
```

Depending on your test setup (if you use junit e.g.) it might be a different subclass of

```
org.pitest.testapi.TestSuiteFinder
```

I experienced the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
    at org.pitest.junit.adapter.AdaptedJUnitTestUnit.createRunner(AdaptedJUnitTestUnit.java:107)
    at org.pitest.junit.RunnerSuiteFinder.apply(RunnerSuiteFinder.java:40)
    at org.pitest.junit.RunnerSuiteFinder.apply(RunnerSuiteFinder.java:35)
    at org.pitest.extension.common.CompoundTestSuiteFinder.apply(CompoundTestSuiteFinder.java:20)
    at org.pitest.extension.common.CompoundTestSuiteFinder.apply(CompoundTestSuiteFinder.java:9)
    at org.pitest.testapi.execute.FindTestUnits.findTestUnits(FindTestUnits.java:47)
    at org.pitest.testapi.execute.FindTestUnits.getTestUnits(FindTestUnits.java:40)
    at org.pitest.testapi.execute.FindTestUnits.findTestUnitsForAllSuppliedClasses(FindTestUnits.java:29)
    at org.pitest.coverage.execute.CoverageMinion.discoverTests(CoverageMinion.java:156)
    at org.pitest.coverage.execute.CoverageMinion.getTestsFromParent(CoverageMinion.java:137)
    at org.pitest.coverage.execute.CoverageMinion.main(CoverageMinion.java:83)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 26 more
```

The exception is part of the runner variable. Print it using:

```
((ErrorReportingRunner) runner).causes.get(0).printStackTrace()
```